# Changing Security Groups for EC2 Instance using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I tried finding it on AWS documentation but couldn't find it..
Is there a way to apply a security group "sg-123" on a running EC2 instance using Boto3?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer:

response = instance.modify_attribute(Groups=['sg-123'])